# Matlab: subplot to .eps axis size

Tags: matlab, latex, save, subplot

In Matlab I have two plots that I want to include in a latex document. I can change the size, and everything else for each individual plot with this code:

```
set(1, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [0 0 10 8]);
set(get(gca,'xlabel'),'string','cutoff','fontsize',14,'fontname','Bitstream Vera Serif');
set(get(gca,'ylabel'),'string','F-score','fontsize',14,'fontname','Bitstream Vera Serif');
set(gca,'fontsize',14,'fontname','Bitstream Vera Serif');
print(1,'-depsc','-r300',[dir_name filenames{f} method{m} '_comb']);
```

This saves my plot to a .eps file in the correct size and such and loads perfectly in the correct size in latex. However, I want to have both plots in a subplot while maintaining the axis size. The above code does not work since the subplot that gets printed seems to ignore the axis size and shows up always in the same size in latex (however big I make the numbers for the axis, it does not matter).

How can I make sure Matlab prints the subplot with the correct sizes? Maybe noteworthy: the size of the subplot does infact change on screen when generating the plot but this is ignored by latex, even though it works fine when NOT using subplot.

--EDIT--

After some fiddling around I was able to provide a minimal working example for the code I have.

```
X1 = sort(rand(30,1));
Y1 = sort(rand(30,1));

X2 = sort(rand(30,1));
Y2 = sort(rand(30,1));

subplot(2,1,1)
 plot(X1,Y1,'gs','LineWidth',0.5,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',2)
axis([0 1 0 1]);
highX = X1(:,1)>=0.8;
for K = 1 : size(X1,1)
    if highX(K) == 1
        line(X1(K,1),Y1(K,1),'color',[.5 .5 .5],'marker','o','linestyle','none','markersize',9,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
    end
end
set(1, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [2 2 15 15]);

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(X2,Y2,'gs','LineWidth',0.5,'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',2)
axis([0 1 0 1]);
highX = X2(:,1)>=0.8;
for K = 1 : size(X2,1)
    if highX(K) == 1
        line(X2(K,1),Y2(K,1),'color',[.3 .5 .7],'marker','o','linestyle','none','markersize',9,'MarkerEdgeColor','k');
    end
end
set(1, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [2 2 15 15]);

print(1,'-depsc','-r300','test');
```

This produces 2 plots with some coordinates marked. In latex I load the file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{test.eps}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code you provided is insufficient to reproduce your problem not to mention partly irrelevant (Why include label bloat when the problem is with the axes).

Comment: @OlegKomarov because reproducing the problem exactly would require over 500 lines of code. The only thing you really need is a figure window with a plot. Even a plot like `y=x` would suffice.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking, to provide a minimal working example that reproduces your issue, not the 500 lines of code. I should be able to copy paste the code and see what's the issue. Instead, I am left wondering what you mean (as many others).

Comment: I cannot give a minimal working example because my plots include a lot of different things; I have a basic plot build from a matrix (X and Y), some of these coordinates (based on some conditions) must be marked by adding a lineplot on top of the original plot which creates a circle around the coordinate. Dunno how to give a minimal example for that except for including the entire matrix.

Comment: Also, each plot contains 5 different lines from 5 different matrices.

Comment: A minimal working example (MWE) should reproduce the issue not the plot. If you have problems with the axis, then create an example with axis settings only. Often, the effort of creating the MWE isolates exactly what the problem is, leading to a solution and improved understanding of the language.

Comment: @OlegKomarov, you're right of course. The minimal working example which produces the same problem is added to the question.

Comment: With your example I get a single figure in MATLAB with two subplots with equal axes. When I publish the the latex, I get the same result, 1 figure, two subplots, same axes. Is that undesired?

Comment: The problem is the size of the image, I would like the image to be about 0.8 times the textheight in latex, but increasing the axissize in matlab does not increase the height in latex unless I create 2 separate plots. For subbplot the sizes seem to shrink to a defaul value, whatever parameters I use in matlab.

Comment: This is not a MATLAB issue! With `\includegraphics` you are setting the `width`, and *"NB. Only specifying either width or height will scale the image whilst maintaining the aspect ratio."* (source: [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics)). Either you specify a size in MATLAB, or you rescale in Latex. Combining the two is not a robust approach.

Comment: Setting the width in latex simply re-scales the images to use a maximum with whilst maintaining the aspect ratio. If I create a huge height in Matlab the difference in width and height should still be visible, this is however not the case. Doesn't matter which height I set in Matlab, the image is always identical in latex (and yes, it does recompile the eps). This is only the case width subplot, if I use plot it works fine in latex, as said before. This leaves me to think it is indeed a Matlab issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a state-like function such as plot or `subplot` to do what you asked, however, if you are comfortable working directly with the data objects, then you can make the changes directly to the axis objects.  Personally, I think after a little bit of practice you get better results by directly manipulating them.

Axis objects are the part of a figure that handles the job of drawing plots in the background of the functions most people typically use, like `plot` and `scatter`.  When I need to do things like what you are asking, I do the following.

```
% Get the image objects
f = figure();
a1 = axes('Parent', f);
a2 = axes('Parent',f);

% Use builtins to make the plots
plot(a1, [1:10]);
plot(a2, [1:10], [1:5,4:-1:1]);

% I think that it is best to add labels and titles here too
% That way you can make sure that everything fits correctly

% Make everything fit
% Position is [left, bottom, width, height]
set( a1, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [1, 1,10, 8] );
set( a2, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [1,10,10, 8] );
set(  f, 'units', 'centimeters', 'position', [0, 0,12,19] );
```

Comment: I understand what you want to do and why it works. I'm having some trouble getting everything exactly the way I want to, but it does show up correctly in latex.

Answer (score 1):

### The issue

The size of the figure is not preserved when printing to .eps with `print()` if the figure contains subplots, unless you specify:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```